# Cassandra PHP PDO Error: CQLSTATE[HY000] [2]

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I have a weird problem.. I'm trying to insert data into Cassandra and I get this error:

```
CQLSTATE[HY000] [2] Expected key 'SITE_ID' to be present in WHERE clause for 'sales'
```

Weird thing is that I'm inserting not selecting.. and I do provide 'site_id' in my insert query.

My query is just simple:

INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES('value1', 'value2')

Comment: so the error is from other section of the code, share the complete code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZAns5Sug That's all I have

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea where it gets this "WHERE clause" and SITE_ID.. when I have "site_id" in lower case and I'm inserting not selecting.

Comment: I fixed it. It appears the problem was the PDO extension itself.. It wasn't working correctly.